# preventing user from taking screenshot

Tags: cocoa

```
 I want user not to have screen shot when a mac application
```

run.and also if user press key combination command+shift+3 he could not be able
to have screen shot.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Why should he be disallowed to take a screenshot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [code in cocoa how to prevent screen shot.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307465/code-in-cocoa-how-to-prevent-screen-shot)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no supported way. See question #18: http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html

but even if you could, someone could still use `/usr/sbin/screencapture`.

Comment: It appears whatever document you are linking to was revised just a month after you shared it... whatever you're referring to doesn't seem to be there anymore.